# How to set user data parameter for Authorization Bearer in sim800c

Tags: authorization, iot, microcontroller, gsm, sim800

I am trying to send data to a server using sim800c with bearer token authentication. Using Postman the config is like picture below :
[image: Postman Config]

[image: Postman Config]

to add this header to my post request I'm using:

```
AT+HTTPPARA="USERDATA","Authorization: \"Bearer [My Token]\""\r\n
```

but in debug console I get :

```
+CME ERROR: invalid index
```

[image: Sim800c Error]

how can I use this command properly?

Comment: Have you found an actual fix?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the quotation marks. Command works like this:

```
AT+HTTPPARA="USERDATA","Authorization: Bearer [My Token]"\r\n
```